# Can we return after raise statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I need to return True Value after raise statement. Here I need to raise statement as well as it should return True value. If I use finally statement, it will not raise exception block and if I do not use finally then exception block will execute with raise statement and after that I will not able to use retcodecmd variable. Below My Code in python:

```
try:
    something....
except ValueError:
    self._retcodecmd = True
    raise SomeException(something)
finally:
    if self._retcodecmd is True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 18):

Returning and bubbling exceptions out of a function are mutually exclusive. It's nonsensical to exit a function by *both* `raise` and `return`, you have to choose.

The `finally` block here will force a `return`, undoing the exception you raised. If that's not what you want, you need to let the exception propagate without being overridden in the `finally` block and understand how to handle the exception appropriately in a caller.

Comment: so any alternative for this situation where I need to raise error as well as I need to execute some other function after raising error.

Comment: @PranjayKaparuwan: Perhaps your return values are too restricted? You can't `raise` and `return`, but you could return multiple values, where the first is the same as what you're currently using, and the second indicates if an exception arose `return True, sys.exc_info() == (None, None, None)` or something similar but better suited to context. But fundamentally, exceptions and returns are mutually exclusive in every language I know of. If you're following the exception path, you can't follow the return path without cancelling the exception propagation, and vice versa.

Comment: @PranjayKaparuwan> do not `return` in your `finally` clause. Then when you raise an error, the `finally` clause will run, and your error will be raised after.